# Which framework to choose nowadays, which would be still performant+able to do everything in it (pros & cons)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Choosing a Java Web Framework now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084169/choosing-a-java-web-framework-now)

Hi All,
I'm thinking about which framework to choose for web applications. There are so many web frameworks and I'm afraid of trying all of them - it could be time consuming and I wouldn't have to found much with simple examples.

I have experience with jsp, jsf1.2, struts1. I can say I don't like pure jsp with tags. Struts1 again is quite similar to jsp in my view but a bit better. I do like jsf, I find it quite simple to use :), but I'm worried about performance. We used icefaces and lack of get support was really bad.

I know there exist other frameworks, like spring mvc - could be good? . grails, ruby on rails, wicket, gwt, struts2,jsf2

What I need, I'd like to have a versatile framework which doesn't restrict me and at the same time it's no problem to create features e.g: ajax.A bit easier to develop in but still fast I would be scared to sacrifice performance for ease of development.

I do not have any production experience with other frameworks I named.Do you have? Could you share it please? What would you use?
Thank you very much.
Any experience appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

> I have experience with jsp, jsf1.2, struts1.

You have my condolences.

> I can say I don't like pure jsp with
>   tags. Struts1 again is quite similar
>   to jsp in my view but a bit better. I
>   do like jsf, I find it quite simple to
>   use :), but I'm worried about
>   performance. We used icefaces and lack
>   of get support was really bad.

I don't care for JSF or Struts.x at all.

> I know there exist other frameworks,
>   like spring mvc - could be good?

Yes, Spring is very good.  It's much, much more than a web MVC framework as well.  It's performant, it's got traction, it's got the financial backing of VMWare.  I think it's the clear winner in the Java EE space.

> . grails.

Grails is built on Spring and Hibernate.

> , ruby on rails,

Not Java.

> wicket,

Could be good.  I have no experience with it.

> gwt

Write Swing, turn it into JavaScript.  I have no experience with it.

I think Spring is a clear winner.  It's been on top for five years and hasn't lost a thing.

Answer (score 0):

- For a presentation layer framework: There is plenty to choose and I cannot really recommend one over another as I have only worked with one or two.
- For a general framework to build your application, I recommend Spring. It is well known, support is ok and it is usually very easy to hook whatever specific-purpose framework you may want to use.

Comment: And what is your experiences with framework you used? And I do agree with you regarding spring

Comment: Struts2 is very straightforward and fits very well with Spring. But I have seen a lot of changes between minor versions, meaning what worked in version X.Y.Z does by design not work anymore in X.Y.(Z + 1).

Comment: I have also used JSF / Facelets, and I liked them a lot, but they are more of a component technology than a presentation framework). I mean, you can have Spring + Struts2 + JSF in your application.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jodd.org/ seems to be a very good, fast and open framework that includes many facets needed for webapplications.

Answer (score 0):

For the presentation layer, GWT with Uibinder could really match your demands :

- you build your pages with xml
  (pretty much like jsf/facelets)
- it's designed to be fast
- it's a google product, with a really
  big community
- it's really well integrated with
  eclipse and easy to start using it